# how to check if a point falls into a MKRect

Tags: objective-c, mapkit

Does any one know of a MapKit function that returns a BOOL or something to indicate whether two MKMapRect intersect or contain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MapKit does contain some functions to help with this:

```
BOOL contains = MKMapRectContainsRect(rect1, rect2);
BOOL intersects = MKMapRectIntersectsRect(rect1, rect2);
```

See the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKitFunctionsReference/Reference/reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008209) for more details and other useful functions.

Comment: thats what i was looking for. for some reason the "jump to definition" is not working on part of the classes especially the MapKit classes. so its giving me hard time discovering all these functions. but thats for another question.

Comment: The "jump to definition" is more for your own code.  Use "Find Text In Documentation" for framework help.

Answer (score 1):

That's some fairly simple math, you could implement it yourself, or you could convert your MKMapRects to CGRects and use the CoreGraphics functions.

Comment: That also sounds like a good idea, i will look into it. Thank you

Comment: Given aBitObvious's answer, mine is a bit unnecessary. I only suggested it because I assumed MapKit didn't already provide the functions.